# Is there a way to make SparseArray distinguish between background values of different precision that are numerically equal?

Tags: sparse-arrays

To illustrate what I mean, consider the following:

```
SparseArray[{{1} -> 1, {5} -> 1.}, Automatic, 0] // Normal
```

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 1.}

As you can see, the distinction between `1` and `1.` is preserved. Now consider:

```
SparseArray[{{1} -> 1, {5} -> 1.}, Automatic, 1] // Normal
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

In this situation, the `1.` has been absorbed into the background value `1` and the distinction disappears.

There seems to be one way to do what I want, which is this:

```
one = 1.;
SparseArray[Unevaluated @ {{1} -> 1, {5} -> one}, Automatic, 1] // Normal
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1.}

However, this makes the list of rules very tricky to manipulate, since the `one` can evaluate away very easily if you're not careful about holding the evaluation. Is there a better way to do this?

## Edit

Just to be clear: I'm not interested in generating the list `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1.}` by itself. What I'm interested in, is having a `SparseArray` object that holds a background value of `1` and has `1.` among it's specified elements.

Also: these evaluations were done on V12.3

Comment: Interesting. I am pretty sure that this is not how it is supposed to work. Casting from integers to doubles should be allowed, but not vice versa. Maybe this is something that you should discuss with the Wolfram Technical Support.

Comment: In version 11.3.0 we get `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1.}`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks for pointing that out. I think that's sufficient reason to file this as a bug.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm not sure I actually agree that automatic casting should be allowed at all. It breaks the fundamental symmetry between dense and sparse arrays. At the very least it should be configurable, if you ask me.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yes, you are right. But, e.g., `Normal[SparseArray[{{1} -> 1, {5} -> 1.}, Automatic, 1.]]` returns `{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}` (version 12.0) and I find it quite convenient.

Comment: Btw., in version 12.0 `SparseArray[{{1} -> 1, {5} -> 1.}, Automatic, 1] // Normal` evaluates to `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`, too. So together with kglr's comment we have quite exactly pinned down when this behavior was changed.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I just got word back from the developers that this is as-designed.

Comment: Weird. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Well, _"as-designed"_ doesn't necessarily mean _"properly designed"_.

Comment: @rhermans Couldn't agree more.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, would `Around[1,$MachineEpsilon]` be an alternative to `1.0` for your application?